# Adding a conditional event listener on page Y scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a css class to my sticky navbar when I scroll down on an interior page. I cannot get the event listener to console.log anything when scrolling down. What am I missing/doing incorrectly?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // call resizeHeader() onload if not home page
    if (top.location.pathname !== '/') { 
        window.onload = resizeHeader()
    }

    //resize header func
    function resizeHeader() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){

            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 1

            nav = document.querySelector(".navbar")

            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                console.log('scrolled')
                nav.classList.add("smallerNav")
            } else {
              if (nav.classList.contains("smallerNav")) {
                console.log('back to top')  
                nav.classList.remove("smallerNav")
              }
            } 
        })
    }

})
```

Comment: Try changing `distanceY` to `Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop)`

Comment: I'm assuming I remove the shrinkOn as well?    https://codepen.io/gabe1331/pen/OOxddV

Comment: You can, yes, but your codepen won't work because of the `if (top.location.pathname !== '/') { ` line. If you want to run it inside codepen, replace that with `if (window.location.pathname !== '/') { `

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: One more thing - consider debouncing this to avoid performance issues (https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)